# Issue while running - http://localhost:8080/ ICP application but it asking me username password?

Tags: ubuntu, npm, webpack, dfinity

Previous Issue

I was facing below issue while running app in the browser.
**Could not find a canister id to forward to.**

Then to resolve this issue I followed below link. [Canister](https://forum.dfinity.org/t/error-could-not-find-a-canister-id-to-forward-to/6302)

I created the canister but stuck at step where we have to run command.

1. `open http://localhost:8080/?canisterId=XXXXXXX`

Then I tried to `dfx deploy` and `npm start` from terminal and now it is running as expected but...

after running app in browser : `http://localhost:8080/`   getting window for username password. I tried my ubuntu username pswd but did not work.

Any idea why this issue is coming.

[image: issue]

Successfully ran npm below screen shot.

[image: success]

Also if I click cancel then getting below mentioned error.

[image: Unauthorized]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I resolved the error basically there is no need to run `npm start` with latest version of `dfx deploy` we get the frontend canister link where we can run url in browser.

[image: solution]

run that url and it works fine!!!